# Can I add a technology after creating a project with T3?

Tags: t3

I have created a NextJS project with T3 with TailwindCSS. I have now realized that I would like to use Prisma too. Is there any other way to do it than copying-and-pasting the corresponding files into the project manually?

I tried searching on Google but nothing came up. The docs don't mention anything either